# How can I join content in Drupal

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm having a little bit of trouble with joining 2 different content types in a view.  I'm am using Entities and View modules.

What I have is about 50 satellite offices and each office has a varying number of employees.  I have created a content type of "Office" and created a separate content type of "Employee".  Using the Entities module, I enter a new employee into the system and assign them to a particular office.

Now, what I want to do is basically build a view where I can look at an office, see it's information (address, etc) and also see a list of employees associated with that office.

I've got the relationships and everything set up so the data pulls over, however, the issue I'm running into is duplication of some fields that I don't want to show twice.

Here's what happens:  If Office 1 has two employees, the data returned shows Office 1 twice, each with a different employee.  What I want is for Office 1 to show ONCE, with a list of all employees at that office.

I've tried grouping options, but that doesn't work right either.

Any ideas on how to get this formatted the way I need?

Comment: Did you try grouping the fields by office? What is the outcome then?

Comment: Yes, I tried grouping.  The result was something like this:  --office1 -> office1(employee1) -> office1(employee2).

Comment: the field that is grouped by shows also up in the row if you don't exclude it from display. I guess, that's the issue here...

Answer (score 1):

Try to exclude the field you're grouping by from display:

[image]